# Difference between `const shared_ptr<T>` and `shared_ptr<const T>`?

Tags: c++, boost, constants, shared-ptr

I'm writing an accessor method for a shared pointer in C++ that goes something like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    return_type getBar() const {
        return m_bar;
    }

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<Bar> m_bar;
}
```

So to support the const-ness of `getBar()` the return type should be a `boost::shared_ptr` that prevents modification of the `Bar` it points to. My *guess* is that `shared_ptr<const Bar>` is the type I want to return to do that, whereas `const shared_ptr<Bar>` would prevent reassignment of the pointer itself to point to a different `Bar` but allow modification of the `Bar` that it points to...  However, I'm not sure. I'd appreciate it if someone who knows for sure could either confirm this, or correct me if I got it wrong. Thanks!

Comment: It's exactly what you said. You can look at the documentation for operators `*` and `->` to confirm this.

Comment: What's the difference between `T *const` and `T const *`? The same.

Comment: @H2CO3 Not at all.  The `const` normally modifies what _precedes it, so `T *const` is a `const` pointer to `T`, and `T const*` is a pointer to `const` `T`.  And it's best to avoid using `const` with nothing preceding it.

Comment: @JamesKanze, that's H2CO3's point: the difference between `T *const` and `T const *` is the same as the difference between 
`const shared_ptr<T>` and `shared_ptr<const T>`

Comment: @JamesKanze Oh but yes. `T *const` is a const pointer to non-const `T`, so is `const shared_ptr<T>`. In contrast, `T const *` is a non-const pointer to `const T`, so is `shared_ptr<const T>`.

Comment: @H2CO3 I misinterpreted what you meant by "The same".  But I am curious about one thing: you write `T *const`, so why don't you write `shared_ptr<T> const`?  Similarly, you wrote `T const*`, so why not `shared_ptr<T const>`?  Why not be orthogonal, and put the `const` after everywhere (since you have to put it after in some cases).

Comment: @JamesKanze Right. That's because I'm used to `const T`. I find it easier to read as well, and I generally prefer it over `T const`. In this example, I opted to write it the "orthogonal" way so that there cannot possibly be any confusion. When the declaration only consists of one part, i. e. just a single type, then it is (or least it should be) obvious that the `const` qualifies that one type (since it cannot qualify anything else).

Comment: @H2CO3 When nothing precedes the `const`, it modifies what follows.  But it isn't always obvious: `typedef int* PtrInt; const PtrInt pi;`.  Despite appearances, he definition is the equivalent of `int* const`, not `const int*`.  (This is, IMO, the killer argument.  Orthogonality is a nice arguement---since you have to put the `const` after in a lot of cases, why not everywhere---but it's not really an absolute.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm aware of what each syntax means - please don't assert I am not.

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't think (at)JamesKanze meant to assert that, but merely to show why he thinks his style is preferable to your style. Nontheless, this is becoming a quesion of style, which is opinion. I think we've all reached a concensus on what they syntax actually means.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

You are right. `shared_ptr<const T> p;` is similar to `const T * p;` (or, equivalently, `T const * p;`), that is, the pointed object is `const` whereas `const shared_ptr<T> p;` is similar to `T* const p;` which means that `p` is `const`. In summary:

```
shared_ptr<T> p;             ---> T * p;                                    : nothing is const
const shared_ptr<T> p;       ---> T * const p;                              : p is const
shared_ptr<const T> p;       ---> const T * p;       <=> T const * p;       : *p is const
const shared_ptr<const T> p; ---> const T * const p; <=> T const * const p; : p and *p are const.
```

The same holds for `weak_ptr` and `unique_ptr`.

Comment: You also answered a question I had in the back of my head about regular pointers (const T* vs. T* const vs. T const *).  :)  I didn't mention that because I didn't want my quesion on SO to be _too_ broad, and this was the question pertinent to my current task. Anyhow, I think I understand very well now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. A last tip that I use to remember about `const T* p;', 'T const * p;` and `T * const p`. See the `*` as a separator in the sense that what is `const` is what is on the same side of the `*`.

Comment: My rule of thumb is that `const` always refers to the thing on the left side of it. If nothing is on the left, it's the thing on the right side.

Comment: hochi - how about const T * p; equivalent to T const * p;?

Comment: Cassio, you can add that in the case of returned type  const shared_ptr<T>, it cannot be used in non-const functions while this is not true for const pointers.

Comment: The rule of thumb is not to look at `const` placement, but `*`; and not to see the `*` as a separator, but instead as instruction that anything to the left of `*` is what is being pointed to.  Since `const int` and `int const` are equivalent, a `*` that follows either is a pointer to a `const int`.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to showcase a simple demonstration based on @Cassio Neri's answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> i = std::make_shared<int>(1);
    std::shared_ptr<int const> ci;
    
    // i = ci; // compile error
    ci = i;
    std::cout << *i << "\t" << *ci << std::endl; // both will be 1
    
    *i = 2;
    std::cout << *i << "\t" << *ci << std::endl; // both will be 2
    
    i = std::make_shared<int>(3);
    std::cout << *i << "\t" << *ci << std::endl; // only *i has changed
    
    // *ci = 20; // compile error
    ci = std::make_shared<int>(5);
    std::cout << *i << "\t" << *ci << std::endl; // only *ci has changed
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`boost::shared_ptr<Bar const>` prevents modification of the
`Bar` object through the shared pointer.  As a return value, the
const in `boost::shared_ptr<Bar> const` means that you cannot
call a non-const function on the returned temporary; if it were
for a real pointer (e.g. `Bar* const`), it would be completely
ignored.

In general, even here, the usual rules apply: `const` modifies
what precedes it: in `boost::shared_ptr<Bar const>`, the `Bar`;
in `boost::shared_ptr<Bar> const`, it's the instantiation (the
expression `boost::shared_ptr<Bar>` which is const.

Comment: @gatopeich So you can `delete` it.

Comment: @Marcin could you ellaborate?

Answer (score 1):

```
#Check this simple code to understand... copy-paste the below code to check on any c++11 compiler

#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
        int a = 5;
};

shared_ptr<A> f1() {
    const shared_ptr<A> sA(new A);
    shared_ptr<A> sA2(new A);
    sA = sA2; // compile-error
    return sA;
}

shared_ptr<A> f2() {
    shared_ptr<const A> sA(new A);
    sA->a = 4; // compile-error
    return sA;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    f1();
    f2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May I suggest the use of `std::make_shared()` (since C++14).