# Why my const ref becomes invalid?

Tags: c++, reference, invalidation

Why my const ref becomes invalid in this code and how to avoid this? I can't copy, this is the bottleneck in my application.

```
class Foo {
public:
    const std::string& string() const {
        return string;
    }

private:
    std::string string = "asdf";
};

Foo foo;
std::vector<std::pair<const std::string&, int>> invalid;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    invalid.emplace_back(std::make_pair(foo.string(), i);
    // after this line invalid[i].first is invalid
}
```

Comment: Template parameter deduction works in such a way that `make_pair` returns `std::pair<std::string, int>` in your call; then `emplace` constructs `std::pair<const std::string&, int>` from that. So the reference is bound to the member of a temporary pair, not to `foo.string`. Make it `invalid.emplace_back(std::pair<const std::string&, int>(foo.string(), i));`

Comment: How do you know `invalid[i].first` is invalid?  `Foo` is not assignable with a move constructor.  Is that legal for a vector element?  (Genuine question - I haven't caught up with C++11 fully yet.)  Does it work if you use `std::pair<const std::string*, int>` as your element type?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Make that an answer so I can upvote it please!

Comment: `invalid.emplace_back(foo.string(), i)`. Constructing the pair is superfluous and you also did it wrong.

Comment: test your code before posting.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Works fine now. I would choose your comment as answer, if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igor Tandetnik already pointed out the problem in your code. FWIW, I don't think it's a good idea to have containers referencing other objects' members by reference in any case - there's an implicit dependence on the relative liftime of objects. You can consider using a [`shared_ptr` to `const string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793333/difference-between-const-shared-ptrt-and-shared-ptrconst-t), as in the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>                                                                                                                           
class Foo {
public:
    const std::shared_ptr<const std::string> string() const {
        return _string;
    }   

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> _string = std::make_shared<std::string>("asdf");
};  

int main()
{   
    Foo foo;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<const std::string>, int>> invalid;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        invalid.emplace_back(std::make_pair(foo.string(), i));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`make_pair` is returning a `pair<std::string,int>`, not a `pair<const std::string&, int>` because the standard requires it to be that way.

```
template <class T1, class T2>
constexpr pair<V1, V2> make_pair(T1&& x, T2&& y);
```

> **§ 20.3.3 - 8**
>
> Returns: `pair<V1, V2>(std::forward<T1>(x), std::forward<T2>(y));`
>
> > where `V1` and `V2` are determined as follows: Let Ui be `decay_t<Ti>` for each Ti. Then each Vi is X&
> >     if Ui equals `reference_wrapper`, otherwise Vi is Ui.

This should work according to the standard:

```
invalid.emplace_back(std::make_pair(std::ref(foo.string()), i));
```

and this according to me:

```
invalid.emplace_back(decltype(invalid)::value_type(foo.string(), i));
```