# How does the control block of a shared pointer behave with const shared pointers

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers

```
const std::shared_ptr<int> x (new int (2));
const std::shared_ptr<int> y (x);
```

copying a shared pointer makes changes to the control block where the 'const' shared pointers point to, does that not contradict the constness part?

Comment: I guess that, in an implementation, either the control block is `mutable`, or perhaps more simply - it's just not an actual member of the `shared_ptr` class; the pointer to it is the member, which doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

`shared_ptr` contains (generally speaking) two pointers. One to hold an object and second one to 'internal' data with refcount etc. If you make `shared_ptr` constant it means you cannot modify these pointers, but you can without a problem modify objects they point to.

If this is a contradicion? For me not, but for sure there are people which would say it is. Kind of philosophical question. :)

Answer (score -1):

The control block is an implementation detail that users do not have access to and should not be concerned with. It is not a part of `shared_ptr` interface and cannot be observed.

It is the `shared_ptr` pointer what is `const`. Which means you cannot reassign it.

It behaves similar to a plain `const` pointer in this regard: it can be copied, but cannot be reassigned.

Comment: "*Which means you cannot reassign it.*" It should mean that you cannot change the members of the object.

Comment: @GillBates You probably confuse `const shared_ptr<int>` with `shared_ptr<int const>`.

Comment: I kinda agree with Gill, a const object means that its members are not to be changed (unless they are mutable).

Comment: @mkmostafa What members are you referring to?

Comment: Im not taking about the int pointer, im talking about the shared_ptr object, obviously, the control block is a part of the shared pointer and  the declaration above indicates that the shared pointer itself is a constant but when its copied, internally something is changed.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin [No I'm not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17793411/1870760). `<int const>` makes the pointed to object `const`. `const shared_ptr` should make the members `const`.

Comment: @mkmostafa The control block is an implementation detail, it is not a part of `shared_ptr` interface. The control block and the `shared_ptr` have different lifetimes.

Comment: yup i agree with Gill's comment. somehow the shared pointer has a pointer to the control block and it alters the contents of that control block

Comment: @mkmostafa The fact that you agree with a wrong opinion does not make that opinion right.

Comment: @maxim 

class A {
int x;
obj* y;
};

now imagine that A is instantiated as const object and the pointer y is also created outside A (has a different lifetime) and passed to it. I think u can not still alter the object that y points to through the const instance of A

Comment: @mkmostafa You may be surprised, but you can alter `obj` through `obj* const y`, this is how `const` works. However, even that is irrelevant here, because the control block is not a part of `shared_ptr` interface.

Comment: @maxim Im sorry i was not clear in my comment. I know that u can alter it but is it correct to do so? you are basically saying the whole object is const and yet through pointers u are manipulating a member of that const object

Comment: @mkmostafa I am risking repeating myself: _The control block is an implementation detail that users do not have access to and should not be concerned with. It is not a part of `shared_ptr` interface and cannot be observed._

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Doesn't matter, the user is asking how compilers are able to make it work. Implementation detail or not.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Does the shared pointer have a member that points to the control block or not?

Comment: @Mkmostafa Usually yeah, like MSVC.

Comment: @mkmostafa The standard does not require a particular implementation of `shared_ptr`. In fact, you can implement `shared_ptr` with just one pointer to the control block, the direct pointer to the object is an optimization.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin so in your proposal u say that the shared pointer will have 'one pointer to the control block'. My original question is: you don't think -even conceptually- that this is contradicting when the shared pointer is constant that you are altering an object through a member pointer (I know that you can do it).

Comment: @mkmostafa The only conceptual requirement to `shared_ptr` is that it behaves just like a plain pointer does, but without memory leaks (and with extra `weak_ptr` functionality).

Answer (score -1):

It can either have the control block member declared as `mutable` (unlikely, see Maxim's comment), or (more likely) it can have a non-const pointer pointing to the control block as a member. Changing values of the pointed-to control block in a `const shared_ptr` [is allowed](http://ideone.com/sGjgk8), just reassigning that pointer isn't when it's `const`.

To take a real world example from MSVC2015 (I know I know), `shared_ptr` has  a member `_Rep` :

```
private:
    _Ty *_Ptr;
    _Ref_count_base *_Rep;
```

The `shared_ptr` can modify the use count through `_Rep`.

Comment: `mutable` is unnecessary here, since `const shared_ptr<>` cannot be assigned to.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It may have a `mutable` ref count object member that _can_ be changed when `shared_ptr` is `const`. In that case, it's necessary. Even though it's just an implementation detail.

Comment: @DV May I ask why?

Comment: `shared_ptr` cannot possibly have its own ref-count member because the counter is shared between `shared_ptr`s pointing to the same object.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin That wouldn't matter, at the time of ref increasing or decreasing both the `shared_ptrs` are known and thus an implementation can ask for it's ref count / copy it / decrease it. You're right that it's not very sensible but it is possible.

Comment: Such a `shared_ptr` would not work because you would not be able to implement its destructor. The ref-counters would be inconsistent.